# Trying to enable wake on LAN on my pc. The moment I put my pc to sleep, it wakes up

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, magic-packet

Windows 10.

MSI x99a sli plus motherboard using onboard ethernet port. 
Google said to enable the following BIOS features:

- Wake on Lan
- Option ROM
- Allow PCI-E devices to wake the machine
- Allow LAN to wake up the machine

I enabled them.

On my adapter settings, I enabled allow this device to wake the machine. I also selected only allow magic packets.

Well the moment I put the machine to sleep it wakes back up. Something tells me it isnt magic packets that are waking the machine up if it wakes up a split second after I put it to sleep.

Comment: If you need to use only the onboard ethernet port to enable WOL (Waker on LAN), don't you think that it is enough to enable WOL on the Ethernet device? See this: https://www.howtogeek.com/70374/how-to-geek-explains-what-is-wake-on-lan-and-how-do-i-enable-it/

Comment: Tried that. My pc didnt wake up.

Comment: Option ROM is for **booting** from network devices, you don't need it. Said this is the waking only happening following those steps? Otherwise you can check in `powercfg -lastwake` to investigate

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -lastwake
Wake History Count - 1
Wake History [0]
Wake Source Count - 0

Answer (score -1):

Don't enable your devices to be able to wake up the computer - disable them! To re-wake the computer just click the power button.

Comment: I stream videos from my pc to my tablet. Sometimes I dont feel like getting up to turn my PC on. I was trying to use WOL to fix that so I could wake my pc up remotely so I could stream the videos.

Comment: Ok.. No need to -1 it.. It was only a suggestion.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.